# How to log everything from serial while paralell response parsing?

Tags: queue, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, publish-subscribe, pyserial

I got stuck with pyserial paralell logging and command processing.
I would like to achieve that I can save everything that is coming from serial port, but I also want to send command to my embedded device on serial port and wait for the response (with regex) and take action based on the response.

Currently, this code on the one hand, can log everything from serial port, and on the other hand, print the same messages on the console.

But it is not exactly what I want, I would like to improve this code.

```
import os
import multiprocessing
from functools import wraps
import logging
import time
import serial

logging.basicConfig(filename='pubsub_serial.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s', filemode='w')


def logger_worker(q):
    for item in iter(q.get, None):
        # HERE IS JUST WANT TO LOG EVERYTHING, THIS PART IS WORKING FINE
        logging.debug(item)


def cmd_parser_worker(q):
    for item in iter(q.get, None):
        print(item)
        # THIS IS NOT FINISHED
        # I WOULD LIKE TO PARSE RESPONSE FOR SPECIFIC COMMANDS
        # IT WOULD BE NICE TO PASS THE RESPONSE IN SPECIFIC FUNCTIONS I WANT TO IMPLEMENT (get_md5_checksum, get_fw_version, etc.)


def ensure_parent(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if os.getpid() != self._creator_pid:
            raise RuntimeError("{} can only be called in the "
                               "parent.".format(func.__name__))
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner


class PublishQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._queues = []
        self._creator_pid = os.getpid()

    def __getstate__(self):
        self_dict = self.__dict__
        self_dict['_queues'] = []
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)

    @ensure_parent
    def register(self):
        q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self._queues.append(q)
        return q

    @ensure_parent
    def publish(self, val):
        for q in self._queues:
            q.put(val)


class SerialProducer:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        self.ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttySC3", baudrate=115200, timeout=10)
            
    def loop(self):
        while True:
            if self.ser.inWaiting():
                recv = self.ser.readline().decode().strip()
                self.queue.publish(recv)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    q = PublishQueue()
    processes = []

    ser = SerialProducer(q)
    
    pl = multiprocessing.Process(name='Logger', target=logger_worker, args=(q.register(),))
    pl.start()
    processes.append(pl)
        
    pp = multiprocessing.Process(name='Parser', target=cmd_parser_worker, args=(q.register(),))
    pp.start()
    processes.append(pp)

    # THIS SHOULD BE EXECUTED IN BACKGROUND
    ser.loop()


    # HERE I WOULD LIKE TO SEND COMMANDS FOR EXAMPLE CALCULATE MD5 CHECKSUM, ETC, AND GET THEM AS A RESPONSE
    # chcksm = get_md5_checksum()
    # time.sleep(1)
    # fw_ver = get_fw_version()
    # time.sleep(1)
    # delete_fota_files()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

I found the snippet here on stackoverflow, it is actually a pubsub implementation. One producer, and 2 consumer.
The "Logger" consumer is perfect as it is. It is doing its job.

But I don't know how could I run ser.loop() in paralell, and for example send some command on serial port.
I guess I need some signaling mechanism.
I need to send a command, and the response should arrive. But it will be in cmd_parser_worker().
I would like to have it in get_md5_checksum(), get_fw_version().